# The column "GeoLocation" cannot be modified because it is either a computed column or is the result of a UNION operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert, database-trigger

Here's the insert code.

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsertedPoint
ON Points
instead of insert
AS
insert into Points(Route_Id,Title,Description,Latitude,Longitude,GeoLocation)
SELECT Route_Id,Title,Description,Latitude,Longitude,
geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + CAST([Latitude] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST([Longitude] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326)
FROM inserted
```

The problem about valuing of `geography`. When i create trigger i get error `The column "GeoLocation" cannot be modified because it is either a computed column or is the result of a UNION operator.`. How can i fix problem ?

So it's `Points` table

[image]

Comment: Is `GeoLocation` a computed column? Would you please show the `CREATE TABLE` statement for table `Points`?

Comment: Yes computed column

Comment: If Points.GeoLocation is a computed column then don't add it to the insert.

Comment: @LukStorms But i have to insert GeoLocation. What is your suggestion to use instead of Computed column?

Comment: I guess you could review the calculation used for that GeoLocation column. Change it if you have to. But I think you can only do it with a drop & add column for those.  And maybe make it a persisted while at it, if that would be usefull.

Answer (score 3):

You can't insert values in a computed column. The principle of computed columns is that you define a computation rule, and then your RDBMS automatically manages it, computing values from other columns as needed.

Without this colum, your trigger boils down to:

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsertedPoint
ON Points
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
INSERT INTO Points(Route_Id,Title,Description,Latitude,Longitude)
SELECT Route_Id,Title,Description,Latitude,Longitude
FROM inserted
```

As it is, this trigger is a no-operation. Unless it does something else that what you have showed us, you would better just remove it.